# Jquery Product Quick View

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am developing a rails e-commerce app, I need to add a quick view functionality on the products page, but not able to find any suitable plugin,
I found few but they are outdated like (jacklmoore.com/colorbox/example1/)  which is good but design is little dull as per today standards, I tried to use (codyhouse.co/demo/product-quick-view/index.html#0) but I think there is a bug in this plug-in.
So please if anyone can refer me a plugin  for product quick view for rails app or in general. Thanks

Comment: Can you explain some more about your requirements please?  It's not clear to me at least what you mean by "quick view".  If you could point to some examples on other sites that might be helpful.  Generally speaking, if you want a load of out-of-the-box jquery functionality you could look at frameworks like Bootstrap http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: What about this one -> http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: @MaxWilliams  [link]https://codyhouse.co/demo/product-quick-view/index.html#0[link] like this one but this source has an error as per my knowledge